# Fibonacci numbers relation

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I was wondering if there was a relation between a Fibonacci number and its position. Is there a function $f(n)$ such that $$f(n)=F_n$$ where $F_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number?

Comment: do you know $F_{n}$ closed formula ?

Comment: You mean $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$?

Comment: no , I mean $$f_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n+(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n)$$

Comment: Note that, even if there wasn't a closed form, $f$ where $f(n)=F_n$ is still a function. A function is _any rule_ that turns a number into a number (along with a domain). So $f(n)$, the way you've described it, is a function. (You seem to have the misconception that a function is any combination of mathematical symbols… this is generally called a _closed form_ formula.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That f(n) you are looking for is the closed-form expression, you can verify its definition [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression):

$$F_n = \frac{\varphi^n - (1-\varphi)^n}{\sqrt{5}}, \quad\text{where}\quad \varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

There is also

$$\begin{bmatrix} F(n + 1) & F(n) \\ F(n) & F(n - 1) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n$$